# Build columns based on specific conditions of data frame rows

Tags: r, apply

I would like to create code in R to capture the name of the column where the value 1 appears for the first time per line.

Later, given that the value 1 is present in the row in question, I would like to capture the name of the column where the value 2 last appears before the value 1.

In a practical way, in possession of the following set of data (example):

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), `2004` = c(2, 2, 0,
2, 2, 0), `2005` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0), `2006` = c(2, 2, 0, 2,
2, 0), `2007` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1), `2008` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 2,
0), `2009` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1), `2010` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0
), `2011` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `2012` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
     `2013` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `2014` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1
     ), `2015` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `2016` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
     0), `2017` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), `2018` = c(0, 0, 0, 1,
     0, 1), `2019` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

I need to get something like:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), `2004` = c(2, 2, 0,
2, 2, 2), `2005` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0), `2006` = c(2, 2, 0, 2,
2, 0), `2007` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1), `2008` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 2,
0), `2009` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1), `2010` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0
), `2011` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `2012` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
     `2013` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `2014` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1
     ), `2015` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `2016` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
     0), `2017` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), `2018` = c(0, 0, 0, 1,
     0, 1), `2019` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), situation1 = c(2015,
     NA, 2012, 2011, NA, 2007), situation2 = c(2010, NA, NA, 2010,
     NA, 2004)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table",
"data.frame"))
```

I tried some possibilities, like using `apply` per line, but I wasn't successful, thanks for any help.

Comment: you supplied identical structures for problem and solution ;-)

Comment: Hi @I_O, the second dput contains two more columns, situation1 and situation2 which are the columns I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with base R only:

```
d1$situation1 <- apply(d1[,-1], 1, \(x) as.numeric(names(which(x == 1)[1])))
d1$situation2 <- apply(d1[,-1], 1, \(x) {
  x <- x[1:16][as.numeric(names(x[1:16])) < as.numeric(x[17])]
  as.numeric(names(which(rev(x) == 2)[1]))
})
```

```
> d1
  id 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 situation1 situation2
1  1    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0       2015       2010
2  2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         NA         NA
3  3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0       2012         NA
4  4    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1       2011       2010
5  5    2    0    2    2    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0         NA         NA
6  6    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    0       2007         NA
```

Answer (score 2):

a solution with {dplyr}, *d1* being your example input data:

```
library(dplyr)

d1 |>
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = 'year') |>
  group_by(id) |>
  mutate(situation1 = min(year[value == 1]),
         situation2 = max(year[value == 2 & year < situation1])
         ) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = year) |>
  as.data.frame()
```

```
+   id situation1 situation2 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
1  1       2015       2010    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    0    0    0
2  2       <NA>       <NA>    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    0    0    0
3  3       2012       <NA>    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
4  4       2011       2010    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    1    1    1
5  5       <NA>       <NA>    2    0    2    2    2    0    0    0    0    0
6  6       2007       <NA>    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0
  2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
1    0    1    0    0    0    0
2    0    0    0    0    0    0
3    0    0    0    0    0    0
4    1    1    1    1    1    1
5    0    0    0    0    0    0
6    1    0    0    1    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stick to `data.table`.

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(dt))) dt[i, situation1 := ifelse(any(dt[i, -1] %in% 1), names(dt)[which(dt[i, -1] == 1)[1] + 1], NA)][
  i, situation2 := ifelse(any(dt[i, -1] %in% 1) & any(dt[i, -1] %in% 2), names(dt)[which.max(cumsum(dt[i, -1] == 2)) + 1], NA)]

dt
#    id 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 situation1 situation2
# 1:  1    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0       2015       2010
# 2:  2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0       <NA>       <NA>
# 3:  3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0       2012       <NA>
# 4:  4    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1       2011       2010
# 5:  5    2    0    2    2    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0       <NA>       <NA>
# 6:  6    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    0       2007       <NA>
```

---

*Data:*

```
dt <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), `2004` = c(2, 2, 0, 
2, 2, 0), `2005` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0), `2006` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 
2, 0), `2007` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1), `2008` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 
0), `2009` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1), `2010` = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0
), `2011` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `2012` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
    `2013` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `2014` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1
    ), `2015` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `2016` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0), `2017` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), `2018` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1), `2019` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```